# Make view fall in multiple rows like text in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have a similar problem to this: [SwiftUI HStack with wrap and dynamic height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62102647/swiftui-hstack-with-wrap-and-dynamic-height/62103264#62103264)

But I want this tags to aligned in **center** instead of left aligned. I tried but can't make it work.

[image]

Comment: Did you ever find solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try VStack with alignment.

```
VStack(alignment: .center) {
    // your views
}
```

Comment: Hi Jeeva, I added screen shot to answers

Answer (score 0):

SkillChipView is just rename of TagCloudView.

[image]