# Breaking Text Pills to a new Line

Tags: swift, swiftui, formatting

I want the pills to break to the next line. As far I have no clue how to accomplish that.

Here is a bit of my code:

```
HStack {
    ForEach(interests, id: \.self) { interest in
        Text(interest)
            .padding(.horizontal, 10)
            .padding(.vertical, 5)
            .background(Color.blue)
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            .cornerRadius(25.0)
            .lineLimit(1)
            .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: true)
    }
}
```

[image: Here is the screenshot]

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/62103264/12299030?

Comment: not really. I'd like a simpler way!

Comment: :) I'd like too...

Comment: Do you want to split it into 2 rows that are horizontally scrollable? Or do you want to keep making new rows until all pills are on the screen?

Comment: until all pills are on the screen!

Comment: @nicksarno, do you have an idea?

Comment: I don't know a straightforward solution, but I posted an alternative that I think would work.

Comment: Doesn't a LazyVGrid help? You might need to set a fixed width on each cell.

Comment: @Ryan it might. Could you explain to me how to approach it?

Comment: a link would also help

Comment: I just posted an answer below with code

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with setting a maximum # of items per row, here is an alternative solution. It basically loops through the interests and adds a new HStack after the itemsPerRow is reached. The numberOfRows can be greater than the actual number of rows shown (I included an if statement so that it will not create extra blank rows).

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let interests = ["One One", "Two Twooooooo", "ThreeThreeThree", "Four", "Five", "Six SIx Six SIx", "Seven", "Eight"]
    let itemsPerRow = 3
    let numberOfRows = 8
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            ForEach(0..<numberOfRows) { rowIndex in
                if interests.count >= (rowIndex * itemsPerRow) {
                    HStack {
                        ForEach(0..<interests.count) { index in
                            if
                                index < (rowIndex * itemsPerRow + itemsPerRow) &&
                                index >= (rowIndex * itemsPerRow)
                            {
                                Text(interests[index])
                                    .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                                    .padding(.vertical, 5)
                                    .background(Color.blue)
                                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                    .cornerRadius(25.0)
                                    .lineLimit(1)
                                    .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

New in iOS 14 is LazyVGrid which might help. Here is an example using your Interest pill.

```
struct WrappedPills: View {

let interests = [
    "Photographs",
    "Travel",
    "Reading",
    "Gardening",
    "Cooking",
    "Painting",
    "Dancing",
    "Music",
    "Hiking",
    "Art",
    "Astronomy",
    "Surfing",
    "Knitting",
]

//    let columns = [ GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 100)) ]

let columns = [
    GridItem(.flexible()),
    GridItem(.flexible()),
    GridItem(.flexible()),
]

var body: some View {
    
    ScrollView() {
        HStack {
            Text("Interests")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                .padding(.top)
                .padding(.leading, 20)
            Spacer()
        }
        
        LazyVGrid(
            columns: columns,
            alignment: .leading,
            spacing: 10
        ){
            ForEach(interests, id: \.self) { interest in
                Text(interest)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                    .padding(.vertical, 5)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .cornerRadius(25.0)
                    .lineLimit(1)
                    .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: true)
            } //ForEach
        } //LazyVGrid
    } //Scrollview
    .padding()

    }
}
```

You can try a few other options with the "columns" arrangement that might suit your needs better.

Paul Hudson has some good examples of LazyVGrid here:
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-position-views-in-a-grid-using-lazyvgrid-and-lazyhgrid

[image]