# How to make a collection like view with cells align independently?

Tags: swift, swiftui

There are three columns, if you look at the images the cells' y axis placement is row dependent.  For example, regardless of the height of each image/cell the cells are spaced so that the row maintains alignment with its adjacent cells left and right.  This creates awkward vertical white space.  I want the cells to move up or down based on the vertical spacial allowance not creating white space in order to row-align with its neighbors.  I like that LazyGrid loads the cells dynamically and reuses them.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    private var symbols = ["keyboard", "hifispeaker.fill", "printer.fill", "tv.fill", "desktopcomputer", "headphones", "tv.music.note", "mic", "plus.bubble", "video"]

    private var colors: [Color] = [.yellow, .purple, .green]

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: .init(3), alignment: .center, spacing: 10) {
                ForEach((0...999), id: \.self) {
                    Image(systemName: symbols[$0 % symbols.count])
                        .font(.system(size: 30))
                        .frame(width: 50, height: CGFloat.random(in: 0...100))
                        .background(colors[$0 % colors.count])
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

extension Array where Element == GridItem {
    init(_ count: Int) {
        self = Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible()), count: count)
    }
}
```

Comment: I might be misinterpreting your question, but I don't think this is possible with a `LazyVGrid` -- if you don't have row/column alignment, it's no longer a 'grid'.

Comment: you cannot do that with `LazyVGrid`, impossible!, but you can make it possible in custom way.

Comment: Okay, I edited the title. I am not married to LazyVGrid.  How can I do that?

Comment: you can do with 3 side by side VStack/LazyVStack, that would be your answer

Comment: I'm having trouble imagining that.  In a VStack wouldn't the content flow horizontally?  Also would all the content scroll together if I had separate LazyVStacks?

Comment: You said yourself, **"VStack"**, V = Vertical, VStack is a vertical Stack the content organised vertically.

Comment: This should be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/62103264/12299030.