# Is it possible to build a simple collection of flexible Views in SwiftUI using Grid?

Tags: swift, swiftui, grid, lazyvgrid, lazyhgrid

What I'm trying to build is really very simple and common component. Here's the design:

[image: design]

Here's the code that I've tried till now:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var tags: [String]

    var body: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 0, maximum: .infinity)),
                            GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 0, maximum: .infinity))]) {
            ForEach(tags, id: \.self) { tag in
                Button(action: { print(tag) }) {
                    Text(tag.title)
                        .lineLimit(1)
                        .padding(.vertical, 8)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                        .overlay(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4)
                                .stroke(Color.primaryViolet, lineWidth: 2)
                        )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's what I got:

[image]

Here are a few additional details:

1. Number of `tags` could vary from `0..<infinity`.
2. Should never get truncated unless a single `tag` exceeds the entire width of the grid.
3. Number of `tags` per row can vary according to the width of `tags`.
4. Tags must be `left-aligned`.

Note: I would prefer a native `SwiftUI` approach if possible without importing any 3rd party libraries.

Comment: Have you tried using Adaptive instead of flexible? If I am correct you need as many  grid in one row as possible?

Comment: @TusharSharma Posted here after trying a few different approaches and failed. Something so common should be simple to implement.

Comment: `LazyVGrid` might not fit your needs. What you are looking for is a `UICollectionView` SwiftUI alternative, but unfortunately even SwiftUI 2 doesn't have a built-in view that would handle all features of `UICollectionView`. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62102647/swiftui-hstack-with-wrap-and-dynamic-height/62103264#62103264) answer though, it should fully fit your needs.