# Preventing the labels to be cutting off from the sides - TagsView

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am building a TagsView in SwiftUI, which can display words as tags. The basic implementation works but it cuts off the labels from the side. I am sure there is something wrong with my algorithm. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

And here is the complete code to create the TagsView. The code also includes test data.

```
struct TagsView: View {
    
    let items: [String]
    let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    var groupedItems: [[String]] = [[String]]()
    var backgroundColor: Color
    var foregroundColor: Color
    
    init(items: [String], backgroundColor: Color = Color.blue, foregroundColor: Color = Color.white) {
        
        self.items = ["iusto", "assumenda", "hic", "omnis", "labore", "dolorem", "aut", "aliquam", "voluptatibus", "et", "placeat", "soluta", "qui", "voluptatibus", "possimus", "velit", "eaque", "commodi", "dolor", "dicta", "cum", "aperiam", "hic", "maxime", "mollitia", "itaque", "molestiae", "nemo", "eligendi", "unde", "tempore", "sit", "velit", "qui", "ut", "praesentium", "fugit", "velit", "error", "aut", "nulla", "est", "est", "similique", "aut", "laborum", "dolorem", "voluptatem", "nobis", "quaerat"]
        self.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
        self.foregroundColor = foregroundColor
        groupedItems = createGroupedItems(items)
    }
    
    private func createGroupedItems(_ items: [String]) -> [[String]] {
        
        var groupedItems: [[String]] = [[String]]()
        var tempItems: [String] =  [String]()
        
        var width: CGFloat = 0
        
        for word in items {
            
            let label = UILabel()
            label.text = word
            
            label.sizeToFit()
            let viewWidth = label.frame.size.width
            
            print("viewWidth = \(viewWidth)")
            if (width + viewWidth) < screenWidth {
                width += viewWidth
                print("width = \(width)")
                tempItems.append(word)
            } else {
                print("ELSE")
                width = viewWidth
                groupedItems.append(tempItems)
                tempItems.removeAll()
                tempItems.append(word)
                print(tempItems)
            }
        }
              
        groupedItems.append(tempItems)
        return groupedItems
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                ForEach(groupedItems, id: \.self) { subWords in
                    HStack {
                        ForEach(subWords, id: \.self) { word in
                            Text(word)
                                .fixedSize()
                                .padding()
                                .background(backgroundColor)
                                .foregroundColor(foregroundColor)
                                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10.0, style: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.continuous/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/))
                                
                        }}
                    
                }
                Spacer()
                
            }.padding()
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/62103264/12299030?

Comment: Thanks! But I am using my own algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there.

---

Every `Text`s have **16** points padding on each of their sides.  And the `VStack` has `16` points padding too. You need to consider them when calculating the width of the label.

```
let viewWidth = label.frame.size.width + 32

print("viewWidth = \(viewWidth)")
if (width + viewWidth + 32) < screenWidth {
    width += viewWidth
    print("width = \(width)")
    tempItems.append(word)
}
```

---

You may calculate the spacing between every two Texts too.