# Can't create a simple selectable tag view in SwiftUI

Tags: collections, swiftui, tags, jquery-ui-selectable

I'm not so familiar with SwfitUI.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65453108/6449292) helper to achieve this tag view:

[image]

But making it selectable is pain & for everything I did, I got many errors...

How can I make this thing work!?

Here is my complete class:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TagViewItem: Hashable {

var title: String
var isSelected: Bool

static func == (lhs: TagViewItem, rhs: TagViewItem) -> Bool {
    return lhs.isSelected == rhs.isSelected
}

func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
    hasher.combine(title)
    hasher.combine(isSelected)
}
}
struct TagView: View {
    @State var tags: [TagViewItem]
    @State private var totalHeight = CGFloat.zero       // << variant for ScrollView/List //    = CGFloat.infinity   // << variant for VStack
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                self.generateContent(in: geometry)
            }
        }
        .frame(height: totalHeight)// << variant for ScrollView/List
        //.frame(maxHeight: totalHeight) // << variant for VStack
    }

private func generateContent(in g: GeometryProxy) -> some View {
    var width = CGFloat.zero
    var height = CGFloat.zero
    return ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
        ForEach(tags.indices) { index in
            item(for: tags[index].title, isSelected: &tags[index].isSelected)
                .padding([.horizontal, .vertical], 4)
                .alignmentGuide(.leading, computeValue: { d in
                    if (abs(width - d.width) > g.size.width) {
                        width = 0
                        height -= d.height
                    }
                    let result = width
                    if tag == self.tags.last! {
                        width = 0 //last item
                    } else {
                        width -= d.width
                    }
                    return result
                })
                .alignmentGuide(.top, computeValue: {d in
                    let result = height
                    if tag == self.tags.last! {
                        height = 0 // last item
                    }
                    return result
                })
        }
    }.background(viewHeightReader($totalHeight))
}

private func item(for text: String, isSelected: inout Bool) -> some View {
    Text(text)
        .foregroundColor(isSelected ? Colors.primaryBarBackground : Colors.textColor)
        .padding()
        .lineLimit(1)
        .background(isSelected ? Colors.primaryBlue : Colors.primaryBarBackground)
        .frame(height: 36)
        .cornerRadius(18)
        .overlay(Capsule().stroke(Colors.primaryBlue, lineWidth: 4))
        .onTapGesture {
            isSelected.toggle()
        }
}

private func viewHeightReader(_ binding: Binding<CGFloat>) -> some View {
    return GeometryReader { geometry -> Color in
        let rect = geometry.frame(in: .local)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            binding.wrappedValue = rect.size.height
        }
        return .clear
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, after wrestling with it a lot, it is the working version:

```
struct TagView: View {
@State var tags: [TagViewItem]
@State private var totalHeight = CGFloat.zero       // << variant for ScrollView/List //    = CGFloat.infinity   // << variant for VStack
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            self.generateContent(in: geometry)
        }
    }
    .frame(height: totalHeight)// << variant for ScrollView/List
    //.frame(maxHeight: totalHeight) // << variant for VStack
}

private func generateContent(in g: GeometryProxy) -> some View {
    var width = CGFloat.zero
    var height = CGFloat.zero
    return ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
        ForEach(tags.indices) { index in
            item(for: tags[index].title, isSelected: tags[index].isSelected)
                .padding([.horizontal, .vertical], 4)
                .alignmentGuide(.leading, computeValue: { d in
                    if (abs(width - d.width) > g.size.width) {
                        width = 0
                        height -= d.height
                    }
                    let result = width
                    if tags[index].title == self.tags.last!.title {
                        width = 0 //last item
                    } else {
                        width -= d.width
                    }
                    return result
                })
                .alignmentGuide(.top, computeValue: {d in
                    let result = height
                    if tags[index].title == self.tags.last!.title {
                        height = 0 // last item
                    }
                    return result
                }).onTapGesture {
                    tags[index].isSelected.toggle()
                }
        }
    }.background(viewHeightReader($totalHeight))
}

private func item(for text: String, isSelected: Bool) -> some View {
    Text(text)
        .foregroundColor(isSelected ? Colors.primaryBarBackground : Colors.textColor)
        .padding()
        .lineLimit(1)
        .background(isSelected ? Colors.primaryBlue : Colors.primaryBarBackground)
        .frame(height: 36)
        .cornerRadius(18)
        .overlay(Capsule().stroke(Colors.primaryBlue, lineWidth: 1))
}

private func viewHeightReader(_ binding: Binding<CGFloat>) -> some View {
    return GeometryReader { geometry -> Color in
        let rect = geometry.frame(in: .local)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            binding.wrappedValue = rect.size.height
        }
        return .clear
    }
}
}
```

Usage:

```
TagView(tags: [TagViewItem(title: "ff", isSelected: false), TagViewItem(title: "yyhuuuh", isSelected: false), TagViewItem(title: "kjhgdtfyughuihu", isSelected: true), TagViewItem(title: "nbyvyvuyv", isSelected: false)])
```