# SwiftUI Snapshot test async view

Tags: swiftui, snapshot-testing

I am following [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62102647/swiftui-hstack-with-wrap-and-dynamic-height) in creating a wrapped HStack. However, the HStack asynchronously calculates its height, which means my snapshot testing become really funky. I looked at [this episode](https://www.pointfree.co/episodes/ep40-async-functional-refactoring#t848) on asynchronous snapshot testing but it wasn't too clear/helpful.

Could someone help shed light on how to use the SwiftUI Snapshot Testing Library (https://github.com/pointfreeco/swift-snapshot-testing) to test my new (somewhat asychronous) Wrapped HStack?

I followed [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/skywalkerdude/0e9753acfbddbdee13d24e0211b055c5) and used this code to create the snapshot test:

```
    func test_wrappingHStack() {
        let view = ScrollView {
            VStack {
                Text("Title").font(.headline)
                WrappingHStack(models: ["Ninetendo", "XBox", "PlayStation", "PlayStation 2", "PlayStation 3", "PlayStation 4", "Apple", "Google", "Amazon", "Microsoft", "Oracle", "Facebook"]) { str in
                    Text(str)
                }
                Button("Click me") {}
            }
        }
        assertSnapshot(matching: view.toViewController(), as: .image, record: true)
    }

extension SwiftUI.View {
    func toViewController() -> UIViewController {
        let viewController = UIHostingController(rootView: self)
        viewController.view.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
        return viewController
    }
}
```

The screenshot I get from the test is:
[image: blank image]

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. All the code should be included in the question.

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1):

This page: [https://www.pointfree.co/blog/posts/23-snapshottesting-1-0-delightful-swift-snapshot-testing#:~:text=Async%20snapshots&text=A%20common%20example%20is%20WKWebView,value%20into%20the%20diffable%20format](https://www.pointfree.co/blog/posts/23-snapshottesting-1-0-delightful-swift-snapshot-testing#:%7E:text=Async%20snapshots&text=A%20common%20example%20is%20WKWebView,value%20into%20the%20diffable%20format).

Talks about how to test an asynchronous view. It's a bit complex because you have to create the diffable view yourself:

> When creating a Snapshotting<Value, Format> value you can provide a function (Value) -> Async, which allows you to asynchronously turn your value into the diffable format