# SwiftUI - Building Grid Layouts swiftUI ios 13.x*

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, vstack, hstack

I am using `SwiftUI` and trying to achieve UI like this to support `iOS 13.x*`, where buttons can be placed dynamically in the grid based on the available space in right side of stack and button size. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/62103264/12299030?

Comment: Than you @Asperi