# How can I add a more rows of buttons in my frame when my hstack is too long in Swift UI?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, swiftui

I would like to make the second row appear when my list is too long.

Do you have any idea how to do that?

Thank you in advance!

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
   @StateObject var vm = SpeakingVM()
   var speakingModel: SpeakingModel
   var body: some View {
       
       HStack(spacing:20){
           ForEach(speakingModel.sentence.indices) { index  in
               Button(action: {
               }, label: {
                   Text(speakingModel.sentence[index].definition)
                       .padding(.vertical,10)
                       .padding(.horizontal)
                       .background(Capsule().stroke(Color.blue))
                       .lineLimit(1)

               })

                   }

}.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 30, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 3)
   }
   }

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
   static var previews: some View {
       ContentView(speakingModel:  SpeakingModel(sentence: [SpeakingModel.Word(definition: "Météo"),SpeakingModel.Word(definition: "Cheval"),SpeakingModel.Word(definition: "Ascenceur")], sentenceInFrench: "Quel temps fait-il ?"))
   }
}
```

[image]

What i would like :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put your data in tags and customize the item view and change it appropriately.

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct HashTagView: View {
    @State var tags: [String] = ["#Lorem", "#Ipsum", "#dolor", "#consectetur", "#adipiscing", "#elit", "#Nam", "#semper", "#sit", "#amet", "#ut", "#eleifend", "#Cras"]

    @State private var totalHeight = CGFloat.zero

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                self.generateContent(in: geometry)
            }
        }
        .frame(height: totalHeight)
    }

    private func generateContent(in g: GeometryProxy) -> some View {
        var width = CGFloat.zero
        var height = CGFloat.zero

        return ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
            ForEach(self.tags, id: \.self) { tag in
                self.item(for: tag)
                    .padding([.horizontal, .vertical], 4)
                    .alignmentGuide(.leading, computeValue: { d in
                        if (abs(width - d.width) > g.size.width)
                        {
                            width = 0
                            height -= d.height
                        }
                        let result = width
                        if tag == self.tags.last! {
                            width = 0 //last item
                        } else {
                            width -= d.width
                        }
                        return result
                    })
                    .alignmentGuide(.top, computeValue: {d in
                        let result = height
                        if tag == self.tags.last! {
                            height = 0 // last item
                        }
                        return result
                    })
            }
        }.background(viewHeightReader($totalHeight))
    }

    private func item(for text: String) -> some View {
        Text(text)
            .padding(.all, 5)
            .font(.body)
            .background(Color.blue)
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            .cornerRadius(5)
    }

    private func viewHeightReader(_ binding: Binding<CGFloat>) -> some View {
        return GeometryReader { geometry -> Color in
            let rect = geometry.frame(in: .local)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                binding.wrappedValue = rect.size.height
            }
            return .clear
        }
    }
}

struct HashTagView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HashTagView()
    }
}
```

Comment: same questions info.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62102647/swiftui-hstack-with-wrap-and-dynamic-height/62103264#62103264