# SwiftUI, Wrap an array of strings

Tags: swiftui

I am using draggable API and I am interested to display an array of game strings in a wrapped line like:

> Playstation Console Playstation Portal
> Steam Deck Xbox 360

What I am getting right now is just one single line like:

```
Playstation Console Playstation Portal Steam Deck Xbox 360
```

I could not figure out how it can be modified and any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import SwiftUI
   
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var games: [String] = ["Playstation Console", "Playstation Portal", "Steam Deck", "Xbox 360"]
    
    @State private var draggingItem: String?
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack() {
                Spacer()
                    .frame(height: 36)
                HStack() {
                    ForEach(games, id: \.self) { game in
                        Text(game)
                            .fixedSize()
                            .padding(.horizontal)
                            .background(.gray.opacity(0.2))
                            .cornerRadius(16)
                            .font(.system(size: 24))
                            .draggable(game) {
                                Text(game)
                                    .border(.red)
                                    .onAppear {
                                        draggingItem = game
                                    }
                            }
                            .dropDestination(for: String.self) { items, location in
                                draggingItem = nil
                                return false
                            } isTargeted: { status in
                                
                                if let draggingItem, status, draggingItem != game {
                                    
                                    if let sourceIndex = games.firstIndex(of: draggingItem),
                                       
                                        let destinationIndex = games.firstIndex(of: game) {
                                        
                                        withAnimation(.bouncy) {
                                            let sourceItem = games.remove(at: sourceIndex)
                                            
                                            games.insert(sourceItem, at: destinationIndex)
                                            
                                        }
                                        
                                    }
                                    
                                }
                            }
                    }
                }
                
            }
            .padding(.leading, 12)
        }
    }
    
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62102647/swiftui-hstack-with-wrap-and-dynamic-height/62103264#62103264) could help.

Comment: @son looking at it and the recommended wrappinghstack api.

Answer (score 0):

HStack -> VStack

That's why. It's better to use List:

```
List {
   ForEach(games, ...
}
```